# Google Calendar importing events from .ics file incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, icalendar

So, I am using a [Library](https://github.com/GameplayJDK/icsGen) for converting event schedule to an ics/iCal file. I added two events. The generated file is like this:-

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:icsGen-whatThe
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:This is a thirty minut event
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20171206T173030
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170612T180000
LOCATION:Nome, AK
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Demo Event
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:icsGen-whatthehell
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:This is a thirty minut event
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20171206T183030
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170612T193030
LOCATION:Atlanta, AK
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Dummy Event
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Now, the events are being imported successfully but the problem is that they are being imported as a **all day** event. They don't follow their actual timing mentioned in the file.

I also passed this file through the online validators and threw an error saying `DTSTAMP` is not defined. So I added that field myself to the file, but still, the result was same. I don't understand what is going on. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: How do you import *.ics file using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using VALUE=DATE which is for all day, try using VALUE=DATETIME.

Also you not using a timezone AND have no 'Z'.  If your dates are in UTC time, add a Z.  If not then add the timezone using an acceptable tzcode from the olson database.  This would most likely just affect whether you got the correct time or not.

If you refer back to the RFC5545 spec when you have problems, it may help.
Google used to reject a lot of invalid ics files outright but I guess it's now trying to make sense of them somehow.  The validators don't trap everything.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [related thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/YTLC-bHUWis).

Maybe you are adding this calendar by URL not importing as a file. Maybe the time zone is not correctly defined in the data so the end effect is that the event times are treated as floating and will simply bind to the new calendar's default time zone in Gcal which is UTC (no daylight saving) as GCal does not allow you to specify the calendar's timezone when adding a new one by URL.

Your option is to create a new secondary calendar in your account with your timezone then import the URL to that calendar under Settings>Calendars>Import Calendars the times should then bind to the destination calendar's timezone.